# Converting .cs to .dll CS0246 error

Tags: c#, dll, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, cmd

Quick question. I have a cs file obviously and I am attempting to create the dll via cmd. When I tr I get an CS0246 error saying that a namespace could not be found. How do I put the assembly reference with the file so that I do not get this error. I am thinking that I need to put the assemblies within the same area that my cs file is. Am going to try this and will post if that was the problem. In the meantime any suggestions are welcome. I do not want to do this in visual studio, so please do not suggest that.

Comment: Quick google query: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f73ea717-0bad-4335-8a35-130847eae231/how-to-specify-dll-library-path-in-csc-command-line

Comment: @Matten Okay...so I reference them which I figured. But does the .dll that I am referencing need to be in the same location as my .cs file? I have my .cs file on the desktop by itself, that is why I ask.

Comment: it should be alongside with your .exe, when you compile it is enough to fully qualify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the `/r` argument (short for [/reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yabyz3h4.aspx)). Keep in mind that a type can live the namespace A.B.C but that doesn't mean that type is included in the Assembly A.B.C. One assembly can have an arbritary number of namespaces with types in it.

```
csc /t:library /t:library /lib:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0" /r:System.Data.dll /r:System.Activities.dll /r:System.Management.Automation.dll CopyFile.cs
```

If your referenced assemblies are in a different folder you can add the [`/lib` argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s5bac5fx.aspx) to specify probing folders.

Comment: I will post code of file in original question but  here is what I did in cmd csc /t:library /r:System.Data.dll /r:System.Activities.dll /r:System.Management.Automation.dll CopyFile.cs

Comment: Where is `InvokePowershell`?

Comment: above edited answer works for the references but doesn't compile because we miss the assembly with InvokePowershell, InArgument and ArgumentValue

Comment: Yes I found that out. I believe that the reference for InvokePowershell is System.Management.Automation but that is my problem because it does not compile when I reference that.

Comment: Ok, I hunted down on my box where that dll lives. See if it lives on the same place on your box and if it is the right version. The powershell dll for version 1.0  still doesn't have a InvokePowerShell type